# Python Class design: attributes

Tags: python, class

I constructed a class:

```
class Foo (object):
      def __init__(self,List):
          self.List=List
      @property
      def numbers(self):
          L=[]
          for i in self.List:
              if i.isdigit():
                 L.append(i)
          return L
      @property
      def letters(self):
          L=[]
          for i in self.List:
              if i.isalpha():
                 L.append(i)
          return L

>>> inst=Foo(['12','ae','45','bb'])
>>> inst.letters
['ae', 'bb']
>>> inst.numbers
['12', '45']
```

How can I add attributes so I could do `inst.numbers.odd` that would return `['45']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `numbers` property returns a list, so a `numbers.odd` won't work.

However, you could follow a workflow like:

- define a small class `Numbers`, that would define two properties `even` and `odd`
  For example, `Numbers` could take a list as argument of its `__init__`, the `even` property would return only the even number of this list `[i for i in List if int(i)%2 == 0]` (and `odd` the odd ones)...
- create an instance of `Numbers` in your `Foo.numbers` property (using your `Foo.List` to initialize it) and return this instance...

Your `Numbers` class could directly subclass the builtin `list` class, as suggested. You could also define it like

```
class Numbers(object):
    def __init__(self,L):
        self.L = L
    @property
    def even(self):
        return [i for i in self.L if not int(i)%2]
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.L)
```

Here, we returning the representation of `Numbers` as the representation of its `L` attribute (a list). Fine and dandy until you want to append something to a `Numbers` instance, for example: you would have to define a `Numb.append` method... It might be easier to stick with making `Numbers` a subclass of list:

```
 class Numbers(list):
    @property
    def even(self):
        ...
```

*Edited: corrected the `//` by a `%`, because I went too fast and wasn't careful enough*

Comment: yes,but how can i get inst.numbers still return ['12', '45'] then. i couldnt figure it out...

Comment: Your even test should be `not int(i)%2`.  `(not int(57)//2) is (not int(56)//2)` should return True.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a silly example:

```
class mylst(list):
    @property
    def odd(self):
        return [ i for i in self if int(i)%2 == 1 ]

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.lst = list(lst)

    @property
    def numbers(self):
        return mylst( i for i in self.lst if i.isdigit() )

a = Foo(["1","2","3","ab","cd"])
print(a.numbers)
print(a.numbers.odd)
```

Basically, we just subclass `list` and add a property `odd` which returns another list.  Since our structure is a subclass of list, it is virtually indistinguishable from the real thing (Horray duck typing!).  `mylst.odd` could even return a new instance of `mylst` if you wanted to be able to filter it again (e.g. `a.numbers.odd.in_fibinocci` )

Comment: I can think of some horrible ways this could be achieved, but inheriting from list is elegant +1

Comment: @JonClements -- I'm pretty sure you could do something like this using `descriptors`, but I've never had occasion to use them.  And inheriting from python builtin types is easy as pi!

Comment: Yep - `descriptors` can be used (and if it were more complex, could well be a practical answer) - but in this use-case, it's overkill, and this answer solves the OPs problem nicely ;)

Comment: @ Jon Clements - you are right, it is a silly example but I was trying to learn smth at more abstract level. I will try to dig into descriptors then...